# python FTPからファイルをデスクトップにダウンロードする方法がわからない

Tags: python3, ftp

#### 前提・実現したいこと

python FTPからファイルをトップページにダウンロードする方法についてですが分かりません。

下記ソースでファイル自体をPC内にダウンロードはできたのですが、ユーザーフォルダに落ちてきます。デスクトップにダウンロードしてくるには以下のソースの何処をどのように触ればいいでしょうか？

よろしくお願い致します。

#### 該当のソースコード

```
import ftplib
from logging import getLogger, StreamHandler, Formatter, DEBUG
## ログ出力設定
logger = getLogger("FTP Test")
logger.setLevel(DEBUG)
stream_handler = StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setLevel(DEBUG)
formatter = Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
## FTP情報
HOST = 'upload.****.ne.jp'
PORT = 21
USER = '****'
PASSWORD = '****'
DIRECTORY = '/r****m/do****d'
## 取得するファイル名の生成
FILE_NAME = 'dl-i201912280911-1.csv'
## FTP接続、csvファイル取得
logger.debug('== Start FTP ==')
with ftplib.FTP() as ftp:
    try:
        ftp.connect(HOST, PORT)   # ホスト、ポートを指定して接続
        ftp.login(USER, PASSWORD) # ユーザID、パスワードを指定してログイン
        ftp.cwd(DIRECTORY)        # 指定のディレクトリに移動
        with open(FILE_NAME, 'wb') as f:
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + FILE_NAME, f.write) # 対象ファイルをバイナリ転送モードで取得
    except ftplib.all_errors as e:
        logger.error('FTP error = %s' % e)
    else:
        logger.debug('FTP success.')
logger.debug('== End FTP ==')
```

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

Python 3.7.3
Windows7
jupyter notebook
chromedriver

Comment: `with open(FILE_NAME, 'wb') as f:` の `FILE_NAME` の部分を絶対パス(`os.path.join(r'C:\Users\tani\Desktop', FILE_NAME)`)に変更してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: with open(os.path.join(r'C:\Users\tani\Desktop', FILE_NAME)) as f:
にしてみたのですが、↓エラーがでてしまいました。
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\tani\\Desktop\\dl-i201912280911-1.csv'

Comment: `'wb'` を抜かしてはいけません。。。

Comment: with open(os.path.join(r'C:\Users\tani\Desktop', FILE_NAME, 'wb')) as f:  で試してみましたが、
 [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\tani\\Desktop\\dl-i201912280911-1.csv\\wb'
になりました。。。

Comment: `with open(os.path.join(r'C:\Users\tani\Desktop', FILE_NAME), 'wb') as f:` です。。。

Comment: ありがとうございます！デスクトップに落ちてきました。python初学者で細かいコードの書き方がわからず、お手数をおかけして申し訳ありませんでした。感激です！

Comment: コメント欄は解答欄ではないです。